# Airflow: wait for previous dag run to complete

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I want to set up a dag there are few cases that I would like to address while creating the dag.

Next run of the dag should be skiped if the current dag is in execution or failed, using catchup=False and max_active_runs=1 for this, do I need to use wait_for_downstream for this?

Answer (score 0):

Should it be skipped or not scheduled to run.... an argument of `depends_on_past: True` in your DAG args might be what you need depending on your requirements.